# Doxygen comments - in header or implementation?

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

I'd like to document an Objective C project with Doxygen. The intent is to document for the developers. The whole project is open source so viewable by anyone anyway.

I created a Doxyfile and after a Doxygen 1.9.5 run I can see some (generic) output. So far so good.

Now I want to enhance the documentation. When writing comments, I am not sure whether they should be in the .h (header) file or the .m (module) file.

Where should they go? What is the difference? What might happen if I document on both sides?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? - "Where should they go?" this is opinion based and not really allowed here, it depends on what you want to provide to the users of the different files, i.e. do they get the `.h` or `.m` files or both? - What is the difference? might result in some different documentation ant different places. What might happen if I document on both sides? Depends on whether the or not the texts are different or identical, identical texts should be filtered out. Double documenting is a bad idea, in my opinion, might lead to inconsistent documentation.

Comment: The intent is to document for the developers. From your comment I get that the answer might be opinionated - that means there is no feature gain one one vs the other side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out some significant difference. If I overlooked something essential, please let me know.

When I created a topic (using `\defgroup` and `\ingroup`) I was wondering why some of my comments just would not show up in the group. Well, the comments were in the .m file.

- After copying them to the .h file (and adding a hint it comes from the header) the group did contain the expected reference but both comments were visible.
- Then I removed the hint to make both comments the same. The duplication in the doxygen output vanished.
- Then I removed the one from the .m file and am good to go.

It seems the comments in the header get better spread where they need to go.

Edit: I found some classes that have their header in .m files. Maybe not the best practice, but here it also turned out to **better have the documentation in the declaration** (header) than in the implementation.