# Doxygen calls graph in big c project with separate compilation structure, lot of conditional compilation defines and functions definitions in headers

Tags: c, doxygen, preprocessor

I have not small c-project with separate compilation structure (lot of modules compiles separately often and often doesn't have function implementation, but only functions definition in h-file - in this case functions implemented in another modules).

See fig.1.
[image]

Shortly I have two problems:

1. I can't correctly build functions calls graph in doxygen, because doxygen can't find functions definitions in another c-files (exept main.c). Оn call graph (after doxygen generation) I don't see calls of functions, that calls into another functions (except functions with implementation in main.c). But when I move other modules functions definitions from c-files to h-files - all right, doxygen see them! But it is crutch and I don't have another good way to see all functions calls on graph. See fig.2. Why and how can I solve this problem?
   [image]
2. I can't correctly build functions calls graph, because doxygen understand conditional compilation defines only for main.c file (look like). In this main.c file function main() call a lot of another functions implemented in other modules. This another functions can be implemented in another modules in different ways in dependency of preprocessor conditional statements (#if). But it looks like doxygen gets only first entrance of implementation of functions always regardless of preprocessor defines... But I want to see the second or third implementation instead of first... See fig.3. Why and how can I solve this problem?
   [image]

Part of my call graph I can show here (as is). I can't demonstrate it in good quality unfortunately... (it is not my intellectual property)
[image]

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Please create a small examople (source code plus differences between default settings and settings you use i.e `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) and add it to the question.

Comment: Seems to be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77340014/doxygen-comments-in-header-or-implementation

Comment: I use doxygen version 1.8.13 on debian 10

Comment: And yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77340014/doxygen-comments-in-header-or-implementation looks like my problem 1 (may be, but with objective c instead of c). And I don't the see solution of problem here.

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.13 is from December 29, 2016 the current doxygen version is 1.9.8 so I think an update is for sure advised / due.

Comment: It looks like more fresh version of doxygen (exits in https://www.doxygen.nl/files/doxygen-1.9.8.src.tar.gz) include binary file doxygen with version 1.8.17 (why binaries added to this archive - don't know, but I tryed to build new binary from this archive - unsuccesfuly: there are no CMakeLists.txt, that need in instruction). I don't know, but I suppose, that 1.8.17 is version of binary file doxygen, but version of archive with this fild should be 1.9.8 and this all right. I sayed about Ubuntu 20.04 on wsl.

Comment: But also (I don't remember how) I Installed today version doxygen --version == 1.10.0 (b4feef86149b9a264be7419ac71e2224cc1781fb). And all problems are the same. Problems unsolved unfortunatly. Also I tryed install doxygen with graphwidth and dot to my windows 11 machine, but I can't find good dot installer (windows_10_cmake_Release_graphviz-install-9.0.0-win64.exe from offitial site https://graphviz.org/download/ contain viruses https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/01670c7e5bf637656bd89cd8484d517f3b5bc77f8666ceb29ddcc17e095b0f61)

Comment: May be you know another comfortable tool for building big call graph?